# Identify file type from URL in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, url, nsfilemanager

For an iPhone app, I am downloading files using URL:

From this type of url:: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx//xxx/ipad.html?operation=getFile&contentId=61768b16-6b44-4d0b-bdcf-d10107d1f328

I am downloading files from server but it may be of type .pdf or .docx or .doc

Is there any way to identify file type from url?

Comment: I guess until entire file gets downloaded you will not come to know about its file type. The other way around is in the url itself add one more parameter for filetype so check your url parameters first and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the follwing NSURLConnectionDelegate method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSString *mimeType = [response MIMEType]
NString *suggestedFilename = [response suggestedFilename];

}
```

Of course it works only if you get them from server.

Answer (score 1):

No, since the filename is not in the URL you can not make an assumption.

But after you received the header for the URL they may tell you what kind of file you will receive.

Answer (score 0):

There's no indication of type in the URL you provided, and even if the URL did appear to specify a certain type of file (e.g. `http://foo.com/bar.pdf`) there's no guarantee that the server would actually return a PDF file.

If you don't want to download the file you can always make a HEAD request to get just the HTTP headers and look at the value of the `Content-Type` header. Or, you can put an `Accept` header in your request to restrict responses to a certain type of data.